# Divide N elements in 3 columns by columns

Tags: php, arrays

I need to write N elements (1 .. N) into 3 columns and need to get 3 values of elements, which are last in each column.

I need to get this:

```
 N ... array I need to get
 --------------------
 1 ... array(1)       // or array(1, 1, 1)
 2 ... array(1, 2)    // or array(1, 2, 2)
 3 ... array(1, 2, 3)
 4 ... array(2, 3, 4)
 5 ... array(2, 4, 5)
 6 ... array(2, 4, 6)
 7 ... array(3, 5, 7)
 8 ... array(3, 6, 8)
 9 ... array(3, 6, 9)
10 ... array(4, 7, 10)
11 ... array(4, 8, 11)
12 ... array(4, 8, 12)
13 ... array(5, 9, 13)
...etc
```

f.e., if `N = 10`, I need to get result `array(4, 7, 10)` and the output table will be like this:

```
1    5    8
2    6    9
3    7    10
4
```

**PS:**
not like this:

```
1    5    9
2    6    10
3    7    
4    8
```

I wrote this code, but it has problems with `N = 10`. Could someone help me or find there a problem in that big condition? Or just make it simplier? Many, many thanks.

```
$count_all = 10; // this is N = 10

$count = floor(($count_all - 1) / 3) + 1;

$i = 0;
$j = 1;

echo '<div style="float: left;">';
    for ($k = 1; $k <= 10; $k++) {
        echo '<div style="width: 230px;">';
            echo $k;
        echo '</div>';

        if (
                        (++$i == $count) or
                        (($i == 1) and ($count_all - $i + 1 == $count)) or
                        (($i > 1) and ($count_all - $i == $count)) or
                        ($i + ($j - 1) * $count == $count_all)
        )  {
            echo '</div>';
            echo '<div style="float: left;">';

            $i = 0;
            $j++;
        }
    }
echo '</div>';
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your array at all and how the first part relates at all to the output you want.

Comment: Sorry for that, I know, maybe its harder to understand, what I need to get. That array with 3 elements are 3 last elements in each column.

Comment: Well in your output, the last column is `8, 9, 10`, but that appears nowhere in your array.

Comment: I think what he means is here:  8 ... array(3, 6, >8) 9 ... array(3, 6, >9) 10 ... array(4, 7, >10). Only the last numbers should be looked up. If you stare long enough at this example code, you begin to see 3D-Sailboats:-)

Comment: only if (n==10) or (n%10 ==0)?

Comment: @Mike: I said, last element of each column.. so why 8, 9, 10?

Comment: @Legionar sorry, I misunderstood you. I thought you meant the elements from the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the **output** you want, you could do something like this (apply html accordingly):

```
<?php

$n = 10;
$cols = 3;

// Get number of cells in each column
$num_left = $n;
for ($col = 0; $col < $cols; $col++) {
    $num_rows[$col] = ceil($num_left / ($cols - $col));
    $num_left -= $num_rows[$col];
}

$cells = array();

// Add numbers to array
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_rows[0]; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++) {
        $cells[$i][$j] = get_cell_number($num_rows, $n, $i, $j);
    }
}

print_r($cells);

function get_cell_number(Array $num_rows, $n, $row, $col) {
    // Make sure cell isn't empty
    if ($row + 1 > $num_rows[$col]) {
        return null;
    }

    // Get number in current cell
    $number = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $col; $i++) {
        $number += $num_rows[$i];
    }
    $number += $row + 1;

    return $number;
}
```

This will produce an array of rows and columns like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 5
            [2] => 8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 9
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 7
            [2] => 10
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

)
```

If you only want the last value of each column, you could do something like this:

```
$cells = array();

foreach ($num_rows as $col => $num) {
    $cells[] = get_cell_number($num_rows, $n, $num - 1, $col);
}

print_r($cells);
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 7
    [2] => 10
)
```

You can also change the value of `$n` and `$cols` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I wanted simplier solution, not using any `for`, but its working like a charm, so whatever :) And yes, I just need last value of each column. Working for every `N` :)

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle code is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Krisztian123/ZE66H/)

it's ready and works a wrote the logic in javascript and you can have a look at the code on jsfiddle.

Only difference I use rows instead of columns so at the end of the rows you will see your numbers plus you will see it on the pop up alert box as well.

Logic is simple You want to display all numbers let's say N=25 it is a loop to show numbers from 1 to 25 simple as that you need two variables where to break a new column (I'm my case a new row)

2 cases:

1. N modulo 3 results 0 or 1

or

2. vvN modulo 3 results 2

you don't need more :) look at the code how I calculate it exactly.

You have the numbers

```
 var count_all = 11; 
 var m = count_all%3;
 var r = parseInt(count_all/3);

 if ((m == 1) || (m == 0)) {
     var first_num = r+m;
     var second_num = first_num + r;

  }

 if (m == 2) {
       var first_num = r+1;
       var second_num = first_num + r + 1;
  }   
 // let's see the array in an alert box
       alert(first_num.toString() + " " + second_num.toString() + " " +                 count_all.toString());

       //now comes visualization

     var g = document.createElement('div');
     for (var i=1;i<=count_all; i++) {
         var t=document.createTextNode(i + " ");
         g.appendChild(t);
         $('#divs').append(g);

         if ((i==first_num) || (i==second_num)) {
                 //new column (in this case row)
                 var g = document.createElement('div');
                 $('#divs').append(g);
       }   

  }
```

Comment: i can write it php as well but i think it is clear enough to rewrite the code in any other language in a second

Answer (score 1):

So the basic challenge here is to split a single array into multiple arrays.

```
$column_count = 3; // define number of columns
$start_array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10); // your input array
$start_array_size = count($start_array);
$final_array = array(); // array to put stuff into

array_walk($start_array, function($value, $key) use ($column_count, $start_array_size, $final_array) {
    if(!is_int($key)) {
        throw new Exception('Non-numeric key value passed');
    }
    $index = floor(($key*$column_count)/$start_array_size);
    if ($index < 0) $index = 0;
    $final_array[$index] = $value;
});

var_dump($final_array);
```

This gives an array like:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(1,2,3,4),
    [1] => Array(5,6,7),
    [2] => Array(8,9,10)
)
```

So when outputting your table you can do something simple like this:

```
$max_rows = count($final_array[0]); // first sub-array will always be largest
for($i = 0; $i < $max_rows; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $column_count; $j++) {
        if(isset($final_array[$i][$j])) {
           $row_string = $final_array[$i][$j] . ' | ';
        }
    }
    $row_string = rtrim('| ', $row_string) . '<br>';
    echo $row_string;
}
```

Obviously you can replace the pipe delimiters and row breaks with whatever HTML you need.

Comment: Thanks for you solution, but: 1. it needs to have `global($final_array);` inside `array_walk` function; 2. its working only for `N = 10`, but not for other numbers. Also for me its enough to get just simple array `array(4, 7, 10);`, I will output it my way.

Comment: @Legionar You are correct about the logic not being correct. I have actually adjusted it to where it should work now.  You don't need to declare `$final_array` and other variables passed to function via `use` as that is the purpose of `use` to give you access to work with variables declared in the calling scope.  As far as output, I was simply going with the thought that you might output you result table by row, so having sub-arrays representing each column would give an easy way to access that data.